# Vert.x SockJSHandler class

Tags: websocket, vert.x, sockjs

I'm trying to build a web socket application with Vert.x, and I have found plenty of examples using the `SockJSHandler`, to communicate with SockJS javascript library on the front end of the application.

The examples are using version **3.5.0** of **Vert.x Core** and **Vert.x Web**, and they create an instance of the class using the method `SockJSHandler.create(vertx)`, bridging the SockJSHandler to the Vert.x event bus through the method `SockJSHandler.bridge`. This last method returns the type SockJSHandler, that gets routed with `router.route("/eventbusroute/*").handler(sockJsHandler())`.

I'm using the latest version of Vert.x Core and Vert.x Web, the 3.8.3, and in this release the method `bridge` returns an instance of type `Router`, as stated in the [documentation](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/ext/web/handler/sockjs/SockJSHandler.html#bridge-io.vertx.ext.web.handler.sockjs.BridgeOptions-).

My question is: what would be the best way to route the **SockJSHandler** `Router` instance to a particular route?

Answer (score 1):

see e.g.

- https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/

```java
Router router = Router.router(vertx);

SockJSHandler sockJSHandler = SockJSHandler.create(vertx);
BridgeOptions options = new BridgeOptions();
// mount the bridge on the router
router.mountSubRouter("/eventbus", sockJSHandler.bridge(options));
```

- [vertx/examples/service/ProcessorServiceVerticle.java](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/blob/master/service-proxy-examples/service-provider/src/main/java/io/vertx/examples/service/ProcessorServiceVerticle.java)

```java
Router router = Router.router(vertx);

    // Allow events for the designated addresses in/out of the event bus bridge
    BridgeOptions opts = new BridgeOptions()
        .addInboundPermitted(new PermittedOptions().setAddress("vertx.processor"))
        .addOutboundPermitted(new PermittedOptions().setAddress("vertx.processor"));

    // Create the event bus bridge and add it to the router.
    router.mountSubRouter("/eventbus", SockJSHandler.create(vertx).bridge(opts));
    router.route().handler(StaticHandler.create());
```

**Code which works for me:**

```java
Router router = Router.router(vertx);
BridgeOptions options = new BridgeOptions();
options.addOutboundPermitted(new PermittedOptions().setAddressRegex(".*"));
options.addInboundPermitted(new PermittedOptions().setAddressRegex(".*"));
SockJSHandler sockJSHandler = SockJSHandler.create(vertx);


router.mountSubRouter("/eventbus", sockJSHandler.bridge(options));
```

Comment: There is no syntax error but the 3.8.4 is incompatible to the javascript side of things. I could not find out what changed and need to go back to 3.7.1 for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the documentation I needed in version **3.8.2** deprecations [documentation](https://github.com/vert-x3/wiki/wiki/3.8.2-Deprecations-and-breaking-changes#sockjshandler-changes).

The correct way to handle the `SockJSHandler.bridge` return value is to include it as a subrouter.

So, instead of using the `SockJSHandler` implementation like the (pre Vert.x web **3.8.2** version):

```
EventBus eventBus = vertx.eventBus();
Handler<BridgeEvent> handler = ...;
SockJSHandler sockJSHandler = SockJSHandler.create(vertx).bridge(options, handler);
Router router = Router.router(vertx);
router.route("/eventbusroute/*").handler(sockJSHandler);
```

One must include the result of the `bridge` method call as a subRouter like this (Vert.x web version **3.8.2**+):

```
EventBus eventBus = vertx.eventBus();
Handler<BridgeEvent> handler = ...;
Router sockJSSubRouter = SockJSHandler.create(vertx).bridge(options, handler);
Router router = Router.router(vertx);
router.mountSubRouter("/eventbusroute", sockJSSubRouter);
```

Comment: What is the ... part?

Comment: That part is the handler implementation for the Bridge Event, depending on the particular application. You may find an example here: https://github.com/MaxDac/vertx-websocket-test/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/test/vertx/websocket/CounterHandler.kt

Comment: @Massimiliano, I have issue with cors even though I added it. Can you please share your code where you are handling the mountSubRouter. Thanks!!